# This collapsable div won't collapse, but works fine on jsfiddle

Tags: html

I have a popup window and inside this popup I have a collapsable div.  If I paste the code for the collapsable div into jsfiddle it works fine.  It does not work on my page.  Why would this be?  Also, the collapsable div contains a slider bar.  The slider buttons don't work either.  Maybe it's the same problem.

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/riverbend120/Wc4xt/3720/)

Here is my html:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                    <!-- POST -->
                    {% for entry in entries %}
                        <div class="panel panel-default">                        
                          <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="media media-clearfix-xs-min">
                              <div class="media-left">
                                <a href="lesson.html">
                                  <span class="media-object icon-block bg-default"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></span>
                                </a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="media-body">
                                <h3 class="media-heading h4"><a href="" class="popup-link-1">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>

                                <p class="small text-muted">
                                  <!-- <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i> time since post -->
                                    <div class="popup-box" id="popup-box-1">
                                        <div class="close">X</div>
                                            <body>
                                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <!-- slider -->
                                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                        <div class="active item"> <!-- item 1 -->
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                        <div class="item"> <!-- item 2 -->
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                        <div class="item"> <!-- item 3 -->
                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                    </div> <!-- end carousel inner -->
                                                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                                                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                                                </div> <!-- end slider -->
                                            </body>       
                                            <div class="top">
                                                <h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="bottom">
                                                <p>{{ entry.body_html | safe }}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <p>
                                            <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <a href="{{ url_for('public_user_page', userID=entry.userID) }}">{{entry.user_name}}</a>
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> {{entry.date_posted}} 
                                            <p>
                                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                         <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
                                                       href="#collapseOne">
                                                      Collapsible Group Item #1
                                                    </a>
                                                  </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                          Hello!!!
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                                

                                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                                                <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
                                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                                         <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" 
                                                       href="#collapseOne">
                                                      See All Entries That Cite This
                                                    </a>
                                                  </h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <body>
                                                                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"> <!-- slider -->
                                                                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                                        <div class="active item"> <!-- item 1 -->
                                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                                        <div class="item"> <!-- item 2 -->
                                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                                        <div class="item"> <!-- item 3 -->
                                                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x120" alt="">
                                                                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                                                                    </div> <!-- end carousel inner -->
                                                                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                                                                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                                                                </div> <!-- end slider -->
                                                            </body>       

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <p>
                                            <p>
                                            <p>
                                            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                                              <div class="container-fluid">
                                                <div class="timeline row" data-toggle="isotope">
                                                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 item">
                                                    <div class="timeline-block">
                                                      <div class="panel panel-default share clearfix-xs">
                                                        <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-gray title">
                                                          <textarea name="status" class="form-control share-text" rows="1" placeholder="Type Subject..."></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                          <textarea name="status" class="form-control share-text" rows="5" placeholder="Type Body..."></textarea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="panel-footer share-buttons">
                                                          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                                                          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i></a>
                                                          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></a>
                                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right display-none" href="#">Post</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            {% endif %} 

                                    </div>
                                  <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <a href="{{ url_for('public_user_page', userID=entry.userID) }}">{{entry.user_name}}</a>
                                  <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> {{entry.date_posted}}                                
                                </p>
                                {% for tag in entry.tagList %}
                                    <span class="label label-default">{{tag}}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        <h1><em>No entries!</em></h1>
                    {% endfor %}        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Did you include the Bootstrap Javascript file in your HTML?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors

Comment: @Jasper Hi, I did not.  Although I think it might be there.  Does JSFiddle have that installed automatically?

Comment: @j08691  There were no console errors.

Comment: JSFiddle includes the bootstrap Javascript automaticly in their scripts.

Comment: I added a line to install bootstrap.  It changed the arrows on one of my sliders, but the collapsable div still does not collapse.

Comment: I think I have a version of bootstrap installed but it is not the current one....